# Ito's Integral's definition: Importance of isometry

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-integrals

I'm reading Oksendal's Stochastic Differential Equations (5th edition). He defines the Ito integral of $f$ as the limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int^T_S \phi_n(t,\omega) dB_t(\omega)$$
Where $\{\phi_n\}$ are elementary functions that satisfy
$$E\bigg[\int^T_S (f-\phi_n)^2 dt\bigg]\to 0\;\;\;\;\text{ for }n\to\infty$$
(I left out a lot of details for brevity, if they are needed, I will add them upon request)

He then says that thanks to the Ito's isometry
$$E\Big[\Big(\int^T_S \phi_t(\omega)\; dB_t(\omega)\Big)^2\Big]=E\Big[\int^T_S
\phi_t(\omega)^2\; dt \Big]$$
the limit in the definition exists and does not depend on $\phi_n$ as long as they satisfy the said condition.

I don't understand why is the isometry needed. To me it seems like from $\|f-\phi\|_{L^2}\to 0$ and the reverse triangle inequality we already get $\|\phi\|_{L^2}\to\|f\|_{L^2}$ which (for $\sigma$-finite measure spaces) implies convergece in $L^1$. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you trying to show convergence in $L^1$ of the $\phi_n$ when what is required is to show $L^2$-convergence of the stochastic integrals $\int^T_S \phi_n \text dB_t$?

In any case, in order to show $\ \int^T_S \phi_n \text dB_t\ {}\stackrel{L^2}{\to}\int_{S}^{T}f\text dB_{t}\ $ (assuming $\ \mathbb E[\int_{S}^{T}f^2\text d{t}] < \infty$), Oksendal argues that elementary functions $\phi_n$ which approximate $f$ both exist and satisfy $\mathbb E[\int_{S}^{T}\phi_n^2\text d{t}]<\infty$. So, to show $L^2$-convergence, we may proceed by showing that the sequence of stochastic integrals $\int_{S}^{T}\phi_n\text dB_t$ form a Cauchy-sequence in the $L^2$-space of random variables with zero mean, finite second moment and convergence in mean-square. Because this $L^2$-space is complete, this implies that the integrals converge to a random variable that belongs to the space. *It is this limit that is defined to be* $\int_{S}^{T}f\text dB_{t}$. We proceed by observing:

$\mathbb E[(\int_{S}^{T}\phi_n\text dB_{t})^2] \stackrel{\text{Ito's Iso.}}{=} \mathbb E[\int_{S}^{T}\phi_n^2\text d{t}] < \infty\tag{1}$

And, for $\phi_m$ and $\phi_n$,

$\mathbb E[(\int^T_S \phi_n \text dB_t-\int_{S}^{T}\phi_m\text dB_{t})^2] \ =\  \mathbb E[(\int^T_S (\phi_n - \phi_m)\,\text dB_{t})^2] \\\hspace{5.1cm}\ \stackrel{\text{Ito's Iso.}}{=}\ \mathbb E[\int^T_S (\phi_n - \phi_m)^2\,\text dt]\hspace{5.7cm} \leqslant\ 2\mathbb E[\int^T_S (\phi_n - f)^2\,\text dt] + 2\mathbb E[\int^T_S (\phi_m - f)^2\,\text dt],$

from which the property $\ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathbb E\left[\int^T_S (\phi_n - f)^2\,\text dt\right]=0\ $ immediately implies

> $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\mathbb E\left[\left(\int^T_S \phi_n \text dB_t-\int_{S}^{T}\phi_m\text dB_{t}\right)^2\right] = 0\,.\tag{2}$$

Together, (1) and (2) imply that the $L^2$-limit of the elementary stochastic integrals, which we choose to define $\int_{S}^{T}f\text dB_t$, exists. As to whether one **must** use Ito's Isometry to show this, I do not know. But, you have to admit, its use does simplify the argument quite nicely, no?

Comment: Thanks, now it's completely clear!

Comment: @DahnJahn, You are welcome.

Comment: @DahnJahn, improved the argument, making it more rigorous than it was before. Please see edit.

Comment: Ah, I see. This just shows how I lack confidence and intuition in a topic I know (so far) very little about. I think I understand both arguments. This one seems clearer, we just show that $\phi_n$ form a Cauchy sequence in a complete space, fine. So what was wrong/unrigorous with the previous approach?

Comment: @DahnJahn, The previous argument is fine for showing the $L^2$-convergence of stochastic integrals, but relies on $\int_{S}^{T}f\text dB_t$ already being well-defined. The current argument shows that our chosen definition of $\int_{S}^{T}f\text dB_t$, as the $L^2$-limit of elementary stochastic integrals (where the $\phi_n$ suitably approximate $f$), *exists*. *Uniqueness* of the limit follows by assuming another suitably approximating sequence $\psi_m$ (so, for instance, $\lim_{m\to\infty}\mathbb E[\int^T_S (\psi_m - f)^2\,\text dt]=0$ holds) and showing that the limit doesn't change.

Comment: @DahnJahn, :) And, you are not alone: everyone learning a new topic *always* starts from scratch. I am sure that by understanding these foundational arguments your confidence will grow. Which is why it is important for people like me to make sure we give you the best answer we can to any given question you ask. Also, being armed with said answer, you can then go back to your reference text and see how (or if?) it fits in with the development of the theory as you understand it so far.